# Python requests has a problem finding the ssl certificate path

Tags: python

```
import requests
send_requests = requests.get('https://www.github.com', verify='/path/to/CAs')
print(send_requests.text)
```

result:

```py
OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /path/to/CAs
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: are you actually passing `/path/to/CAs`, or is it just a dummy value? better question, what is the rough format of the actual argument to `verify`, and have you confirm that the path exists.

Comment: but this is described in the documentation of the requests library i am not mistaken

Comment: it is True or False to allow verification of the ssl

Comment: well, i am not arguing that the usage is wrong. in fact I believe it looks right to me. however, I am curious about the syntax of the path you are passing as an argument, and whether the file or path actually exists.

Comment: as described in the documentation CAs means certificate authorities (CA)

Comment: but when i set verify=True it works

Comment: the argument to verify can be both a bool or a path to a file, i believe

Comment: it is erroring because verify='/some/invalid/path' - most likely scenario, the cert path indicated does not exist on the local drive.

Comment: usually string argument points to a custom cert .pem file, like so: /Users/<user>/my_cert.pem

Comment: So what is the solution what should I do for it to work?

Comment: ensure that the path exists, or else just pass a boolean argument to use the default cert location: `verify=True`; but note that this is already the default behavior, so `verify` can be omitted in this case.

Comment: ok bro i have no choice i will use the default parameters thank you so much for replying me

Comment: curious, was there a reason you needed to pass in the `verify` parameter?

Comment: yeah i wanted to verify a particular path but it seems not working

Comment: well, honestly I'm not sure what you mean by that. however, just a note that by path I believe they mean a filepath on the local drive.

Comment: yeah that's right i read that in the documentation if you have any solution please tell me